# How to override default file.separator?

Tags: java, path

I am using Windows 7.
Here is my code:

```
public class DriveLettersList {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.setProperty( "file.separator", "/" );

        System.out.println( System.getProperty( "file.separator" ) );
        System.out.println( Paths.get( "hello", "my", "word" ) );
}
```

The output was confusing:

```
/
hello\my\word
```

Why Paths.get returns the default path separator for Windows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the javadoc of [`Paths.get(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29)

> The details as to how the Strings are joined is provider specific but
>   typically they will be joined using the `name-separator` as the
>   separator.

where the name separator can be retrieved with

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()
```

Where, on Windows with `WindowsFileSystem`, it is [implemented as](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystem.java)

```
@Override
public String getSeparator() {
    return "\\";
}
```

With this `FileSystem` implementation, you can't change it.

This might be different on Unix systems. Actually, [it seems it isn't](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystem.java#UnixFileSystem.getSeparator%28%29)

```
public final String getSeparator() {
    return "/";
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get " hello/my/word " without doing something like (.replaceAll....)

Comment: @nikopol86 Not with this implementation, no. It always returns the value from the String literal. This can't be changed.